# Method save and delete Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have problem about angularjs. Please help me! i watch clip [clip]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8FRBGTJ020 and do similar code but method save and delete does not excute.

my html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app ="SimpleController">
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="RoleList" ng-init="initialize['Ready']">
            <h1>List Role</h1>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat = "item in items">
                    [{[ $index ]}] :[{[ item.roleName ]}] :[{[item.roleDescription]}]
                    <button ng-click="delItem(item)">Del</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        Name: <input type="text" name="name" ng-model ="currentItem.name"/>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Description : <input type="text" name="description" ng-model="currentItem.description" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <button ng-click="saveItem()">save</button>
            </form>
            <pre>currentItem: [{[currentItem|json ]}]</pre>
            <pre> items: [{[items | json]}]</pre>

    </div> 
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}jquery/angular.min.js"></script>     
        <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}jquery/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}jquery/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
        <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}jquery/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
        <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}jquery/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
        <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/demoapp.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

my js:

```
    var SimpleController = angular.module('SimpleController',['ngCookies','ngResource']);

SimpleController.config(function($interpolateProvider)
{
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[{[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']}]');
});

SimpleController.run(function($rootScope,$log,$http,$cookies){
    $http.defaults.headers.common['X_CSRFToken'] = $cookies['csrktoken'];
});

SimpleController.factory('ModelUtils', function($http, $log){

    var ModelUtils = {
        get: function(url,id){
            $http.get(url +id+ '/').then(function(response){response.data});    
        },
        create: function(url, obj){
            return $http.post(url, obj),
                success(function(response, status, headers, config){
                    angular.extend(obj, response);
                }).error(function(response, status, headers, config){
                    console.log(data)
                });
        },
        save: function(url, obj){
            if (angular.isDefined(obj.id)) {
                return $http.put(url +obj.id+ '/',obj).success(function(response, status, header,config){
                    angular.extend(obj, response);
                }).error(function(response, status, headers, config){
                    console.log(data)});
            }else {
                return this.create(url, obj);
            }
        },
        del: function(url, obj){
            return $http.delete(url +obj.id+ '/');
        }
    };
    return ModelUtils;
});

SimpleController.controller('RoleList', function RoleList($scope,$log,$http,ModelUtils){
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.initialize = function(data){
        $log.log('initialize',data);
        $scope.initData = data;
    };
    $scope.loadItems = function(){
//      $scope.items = $http.get('http://localhost:8000/myapp/role/').then(function(response){
//          return response.data;       
        $http.get('http://localhost:8000/myapp/role/')
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.items =  data;
        }).error(function(data){
            console.log(data)
            //$scope.items =  data;
        });
    };
    $scope.loadItems();
    $scope.currenItem = {};

    $scope.saveItem= function(){
        ModelUtils.save('http://localhost:8000/myapp/role/',$scope.currenItem).then(function(){
            $scope.loadItems();
            $scope.currentItem = {};
        });
    };
    $scope.delItem = function(item){
        ModelUtils.del('http://localhost:8000/myapp/role/',item).then(function(){
            $scope.loadItems(); 
        });
    };

});
```

and my error:

```
ReferenceError: success is not defined
at Object.ModelUtils.create (http://localhost:8000/static/js/demoapp.js:22:5)
at Object.ModelUtils.save (http://localhost:8000/static/js/demoapp.js:35:17)
at k.RoleList.$scope.saveItem (http://localhost:8000/static/js/demoapp.js:66:14)
at http://localhost:8000/static/jquery/angular.min.js:177:3
at http://localhost:8000/static/jquery/angular.min.js:194:165
at k.$eval (http://localhost:8000/static/jquery/angular.min.js:112:68)
at k.$apply (http://localhost:8000/static/jquery/angular.min.js:112:346)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/static/jquery/angular.min.js:194:147)
at HTMLButtonElement.n.event.dispatch (http://localhost:8000/static/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js:3:8066)
at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (http://localhost:8000/static/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js:3:4774) angular.min.js:92
POST http://localhost:8000/myapp/role/ 400 (BAD REQUEST) angular.min.js:79
```

and error in my js:

```
success(function(response, status, headers, config){
                angular.extend(obj, response);

return this.create(url, obj);

$scope.saveItem= function(){
    ModelUtils.save('http://localhost:8000/myapp/role/',$scope.currenItem).then(function(){
        $scope.loadItems();
        $scope.currentItem = {};
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
return $http.post(url, obj),
                success(function(response, status, headers, config){
```

By

```
return $http.post(url, obj).
                success(function(response, status, headers, config){
```

Also, I suggest you to not mix callbacks and promise ... because it complexify your code. Prefer using always

```
return $http.[verb]().then()
```

it is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks! I had fixed it but i have a different error: POST http://localhost:8000/myapp/role/ 400 (BAD REQUEST)

Comment: You can check your request and its parameters in chrome/F12/network tab. Something in the request make your request rejected by the backend.

Comment: Do not hesitate to validate the response if it is the right one.